# Customize review notification of suggested edits to other reviews

Tags: support, review, notifications, top-bar

There is a notification of the approximate number of suggested edits in the queue in the top bar next to the Review link. It displays even after the user finishes his or her limit of 20. (At 10k it sums a number of additional queues.)

I think having an option in review page to customize which review queue is notified in the bar would be useful to:

- remove questions and bad feeling about reaching the limit.
- give a user interested in a different review queue the ability to see its status.